# How to wrap radio button inside label for rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-4, radio-button, label

I would like to create some radio buttons inside labels.
The Rails way of writing it which i know is by using radio_button_tag and label_tag.

```
<%= radio_button_tag 'tone', tone, false, id: "tone-#{tone}" %>
<%= label_tag "tone-#{tone}", jp_name %>
```

which will generate these:

```
<input type="radio" name="tone" id="tone-red" value="red">
<label for="tone-red">赤</label>
<input type="radio" name="tone" id="tone-blue" value="blue">
<label for="tone-blue">青</label>
```

But due to the spaces between the text and the radio button, the in between spaces was unclickable. I would like to fix it by wrapping the radio buttons inside the label.

```
<label for="tone-red">赤
  <input type="radio" name="tone" id="tone-red" value="red">
</label>
```

Is there a way to generate these kind of html with Rails style?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/21d34zqt/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work

```
<%= label_tag "tone-#{tone}", jp_name do %>
  <%= radio_button_tag 'tone', tone, false, id: "tone-#{tone}" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks didn't know it was so easy.

The jp_name didn't got show anymore so I have to change it to this:
    `<%= label_tag "tone-#{tone}" do %>
     <%= radio_button_tag 'tone', tone, false, id: "tone-#{tone}" %>
     <%= jp_name %>
     <% end %>`